# How to input additional data into the network when high-level APIs are being used in MXNet

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I am studying MXNet framework and I need to input a matrix into the network during every iteration. The matrix is stored in external memory, it is not the training data and it is updated by the output of the network at the end of each iteration. During the iteration, the matrix must be input into the network.

If I use high level APIs, i.e.

`model = mx.mod.Module(context=ctx, symbol=sym)
... ...
model.fit(train_data_iter, begin_epoch=begin_epoch, 
          end_epoch=end_epoch, ......)`

Can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.fit()` doesn't provide the functionality that you're looking for. However what you want to achieve is extremely easy to do in Gluon API of Apache MXNet. With Gluon API, you write a 7-line code for your training loop, rather than using a single `model.fit()`. This is a typical training loop code:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    for data, label in train_data:
        # forward + backward
        with autograd.record():
            output = net(data)
            loss = softmax_cross_entropy(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        trainer.step(batch_size)  # update parameters
```

So if you wanted to feed the output of your network back into input, you can easily achieve that. To get started on Gluon, I recommend the [60-minute Gluon Crash Course](https://gluon-crash-course.mxnet.io/). To become an expert in Gluon, I recommend [Deep Learning - The Straight Dope](https://gluon.mxnet.io/) book as well as a comprehensive set of tutorials on the main MXNet website: http://mxnet.apache.org/tutorials/index.html